# PCB heater power considerations - sanity check

Tags: power, pcb, heat

I'm designing a PCB heater capable of heating to 55°C in a 20°C environment.

Given the trace length/width that I decided to use, I used the Saturn PCB Design tool to calculate what amperage I would need to get the desired result. The tool estimated that the trace will have a resistance of 1.5 Ohm, a voltage drop of 8.5 V and 5.7 A will be drawn to reach the wanted temperature, effectively using **48.5 W** of power.

[image]

All of this means that, considering heating element only, I would (at least) need an 8.5 V PSU capable of delivering 5.7 A. Of course 8.5 V PSUs don't exist, and even if they do I would get something more capable of that to have a safety margin. So let's say I use a 12 V PSU: to achieve the 48.5 W needed it would only have to draw 4 A of current, but the resitance in the circuit would always be 1.5 Ohm, effectively drawing 8 A of current (too much).

To solve this, and to have some control on the temperature, I can add an N-Channel MOSFET and regulate the Gate voltage (with PWM + RC filter) to add the right resistance to the circuit and get the desired power draw, ranging from 0 to 48.5 W.

The MOSFET I selected is [BUK9M156-100E](https://www.mouser.it/datasheet/2/916/BUK9M156_100E-1539681.pdf), which is suitable for microcontroller projects and can withstand ~100 V and more than 8 A (if thermals are managed correctly).

By looking at the graph below I understand that the Vgs range suitable for my application is between 2 V and 2.8 V, which of course needs to be verified with the actual hardware in hand.

[image]

The voltage after the heating element will be 12 - 8.5 = 3.5 V, which by going into the MOSFET will be dissipated into 4^2 * 0.15 Ohm = 2.4 W. This considering a max load situation of 4 A @ 12 V.

[image]

2.4 W seems pretty doable to me with good PCB design, also the MOSFET is rated for 36 W.
[image]

Here is the schematic for the heater portion, I still need to select many components and do the rest so bear with me.
[image]

The rest of the circuit consists of an ESP32, IRM-60-12 AC/DC brick, AP2112K LDO for the ESP32 and an INA226 to monitor current from a shunt resistor.

Being my first high power project I'd like a sanity check, do these calculations make sense?

Comment: Can you draw  a schematic example with the tool (edit the question)

Comment: @VoltageSpike you mean a schematic of the circuit?

Comment: Looks good, thanks

Comment: is the INA226 used in the heating circuit?

Comment: @VoltageSpike I haven't made the sch yet, but yes I will be using it with a shunt to monitor the current going through the heater. I have yet to decide where to put the shunt, before or after the heater+MOSFET pair. I need to study the matter before taking a decision.

Comment: Maybe consider a MOSFET with lower Rds(on) at 5V (assuming that's your drive voltage). You can drive it with a really low PWM frequency to reduce switching losses even without a gate driver. Typically you may have to pick one with lower Vds- unlike BJTs high Vds ratings come with significant compromise in Rds(on). You can get MOSFETs with Rds(on) in the low mΩ easily. As other have said, I would consider (approximately) doubling the minimum necessary heater power and using closed-loop control.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany my drive voltage of the MOSFET will be 3.3V, because thats the logic level of the ESP32, based on Id-Vgs graph I posted 3.3V is more than ok to get the Amps I need. The AC/DC brick I choose is 60 W rated, which is more than the theoretical maximum I will need of 48.5 W, so I should be good there. I will for sure implemente a closed loop control once I get a basic implementation of the whole thing working. Just to make sure, is it correct to say that with a 12 V PSU, if the heater has voltage drop of 8.5 V the FET will receive 3.5 V as Vds?

Comment: It's poor practice to depend on the *typical* Id-Vgs graph rather than the guaranteed Rds(on) at a certain voltage. You may or may not get away with it in any given case. The MOSFET will drop Rds * Id when it is 'on', and power dissipation of the MOSFET will be Id*Id*Rds.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I agree that you get more 'certainty' when the MOSFET is fully on, but what other way do I have to vary the circuit resistance to get a certain power draw? What I'm doing here is basically a variable load, if I look at other examples online people always use a N-channel mosfet driven by an OpAmp to get a variable load. Only thing I'm doing different here is using a filtered PWM to drive the MOSFET instead of the OpAmp (same result). I will have check Vgs values experimentally and not rely on the graph, I agree, but apart from this I have no clue why this wouldn't work.

Comment: You should use PWM and turn the heater on and off rather than trying to drive the MOSFET in a linear mode. The latter will cook the MOSFET very quickly unless it has a big heat sink and it may fail before that from SOA violations. Eg. a 2Ω heater would give 72W with the MOSFET fully on and worst case is 18W for the heater with the MOSFET also dissipating 18W. With a 10mΩ Rds(on) MOSFET the maximum conduction power dissipation is at 100% power and would be only 0.36W. Almost two orders of magnitude better.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a MOSFET in linear mode it will create a hotspot on your PCB. If the goal of a pcb heater is to make a flat surface at a homogenous temperature, that could be a problem.

Note the 36W rating of this MOSFET is given with the board magically cooled to 25°C. If you put a copper pour on the drain, you will have to calculate its thermal impedance. 2.5W is quite a lot for such a small part, unless the PCB is cooled by contact through a squishy pad.

The simulation provided by Saturn Toolkit most likely rests on a number of prior assumptions which are not clear. For example a PCB mounted vertically will have much better convection cooling than if it is mounted horizontally, and if you use it to heat something, that would also have to be taken into account. So the power calculated by Saturn should be taken with a grain of salt.

Since the 4mm trace width is quite large, I'd recommend working with 24V and using thinner traces to adjust the resistance value to something easier to drive with simple PWM. Also if you use the cheap Chinese manufacturers, you have to read the docs, because quite often the copper is only 18µm, which will double your resistance.

If you don't want to use PWM due to noise concerns, then you'd have to drive the MOSFET with an opamp, and use the copper trace as the current sense resistor. There is no need for a separate sense resistor in this case. Driving the gate directly with a microcontroller DAC would require a fast control algorithm, otherwise the MOSFET will go in thermal runaway quickly.

Comment: I'm indeed using an heatsink on back of the MOSFET with a squishy pad on exposed copper. Anyway your idea of upping the voltage to lower the amps and thus less power loss no matter what MOSFET/gate driving technique use is awesome. So now with 24 V, to obtain the 48.5 W theoretical needed power (I agree not to trust Saturn pcb too much and plan for more), I would only need 2 A. With a 3 mm trace width its even less. Now with 150 mOhm RdsOn I get 0.6 W power loss on the MOSFET. Combined with the heatsink and all this should now be a lot better, right?

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you don't want any capacitance on the FET, or a voltage divider. The fet needs to be fully off or fully on. If it isn't power will be dissipated in the FET and that is undesirable and could break the FET.

Lets think about the fully on situation of the FET. 150mΩ*8A^2 is 9.6W. If for some reason this circuit get's stuck on even in the fully on situation, it will experience a 40C temp rise (~9.6W * 4.16K/W (junction resistance)= ~40K or 40C) which isn't bad considering it can take 175C but you might not want to handle that much power being dissipated in your design in one spot.

Really you want to rougly calc the power being dissipated in the FET and junction temp, because the temperature of the part should not be exceeded.

The other problem is when switching,  transition where the resistance is near the middle (1.5Ohms for the FET) so that would be 3Ohms total and 1.5Ω*3A^2=13.5W for the FET, which it could handle being in this state also, it would probably be in the 55C range at 13.5W.

So the FET could handle anything you could throw at it. It's probably better to have the FET switch on and off as fast as possible. Also no current shunt is necessary, you already have a good idea of how much power is going into the circuit (9.6W) and lets say a duty cycle of 50% is used... then you'll get 4.55W, and a 10% duty cycle would be 0.96W.

A better way for feedback would be to get a chip temp monitor or an NTC thermistor and measure that. You can then run a PID and do temperature control.

Comment: I would prefer not to use the MOSFET as a switch because I will never need it to be fully on and I wouldn't want to introduce any switching noise in the circuit. Also I saw many examples of using a MOSFET as a load driver in an heater circuit, so I would feel confident about that. All I'm worried are the calculations in the original post,  you didn't complain so I would assume they are sound. I indeed will add an NTC thermistor to have over temp protection, forgot to mention it. I agree that the shunt is not necessary, but for educational purposes I would like to use it to learn about it.

Comment: The fully on was only for heat analysis its important to look at the edge cases. The NTC would also be used for temp control if you used a digital control loop. Iearning PID's would be very useful as they are used everywhere.

Comment: I will indeed be implementing a PID after having tried a basic, manual non-PID solution. Just to make sure, is it correct to say that with a 12 V PSU, if the heater has voltage drop of 8.5 V the FET will receive 3.5 V as Vds?